# Why are the items in my array not displaying on separate lines?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am wanting to make it so each item in my array is displayed on separate lines, but my "\n" isn't working. Do I have it in the wrong place? I've tried to put it in other locations but doesn't seem to make a difference. My goal of the function is to loop through the array.

```js
var employees = [];
employees[0] = "Zak";
employees[1] = "Jessica";
employees[2] = "Mark";
employees[3] = "Fred";
employees[4] = "Sally";

var showEmployee = function (names) {
    'use strict';
    showEmployee = employees;
    return names;
};

showEmployee(employees);
window.console.log(showEmployee + "\n");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were adding a newline to the end of the array, you need to add it between each element in the array (using join)

```js
var employees = [];
employees[0] = "Zak";
employees[1] = "Jessica";
employees[2] = "Mark";
employees[3] = "Fred";
employees[4] = "Sally";

var showEmployee = function (names) {
    'use strict';
    showEmployee = employees;
    return names;
};

showEmployee(employees);
window.console.log(showEmployee.join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if this helps

```js
var employees = [];
employees[0] = "Zak";
employees[1] = "Jessica";
employees[2] = "Mark";
employees[3] = "Fred";
employees[4] = "Sally";

var showEmployee = function (names) {
  names.map((name) => window.console.log(name));
};

showEmployee(employees);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through your array and logging each employee instead:

```
employees.forEach(function(employee) {
    console.log(employee)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only adding `\n` at the very end of your output while it seems like you expect `\n` to be printed after each element in the array. You could achieve your desired results by using `join` method:

```js
var employees = [];
employees[0] = "Zak";
employees[1] = "Jessica";
employees[2] = "Mark";
employees[3] = "Fred";
employees[4] = "Sally";

function showEmployee(a) {
  return a.join(',\n')
}

console.log(showEmployee(employees));
```